# Etimologia da palavra barraca ou barraco?

Tags: etimologia, morfologia

Eu estava a ver os derivados do radical **barr** e vi que o produto com o sufixo **-ac(o/a)** fica **barr-ac-o** ou **barr-ac-a**... É de notar que são lexemas diferentes **barr+o** ou **barr+a**, tendo [*barra*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/barra) origem no sinónimo latim e sendo *barro* de [*origem controversa*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/barro) segundo o dicionário priberam.

(Só para acrescentar outro exemplo com o sufixo **-ac(o/a)** ele também gera adjectivos denominais como *maní-ac-o* e *maní-ac-a* e toponímicos como *austrí-ac-o* ou *austrí-ac-a*.)

Alguém consegue acrescentar fontes para a origem da palavra barraco ou barraca e se derivam de barro ou barra?

Comment: A palavra *barraco* sempre me pareceu alteração de *barraca* para ofender, como «Isso aí não é uma casa! É o barraco da sua bisavó cega de um olho!». Mas acho que isto veio depois.

Comment: @Schilive os sufixos têm uma semântica própria que transmitem à palavra derivada, por exemplo o sufixo derivacional "ão" que faz do radical algo "grande" como doming**ão** ou brasileir**ão**. Em sufixos como "aco", "eco", "zeco" o sentido pode ser depreciativo, como a forma mais comum é com índice temático **a** usar um **o** pode dar essa impressão por dar mais evidência à palavra, mas em Portugal não se entenderia uma intenção de ofender com essa alteração, sendo mais comum barracão para arrecadações; diga-se que hoje em dia vai sendo rara a existência de barracas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Barra" vem, provavelmente, de uma palavra franca (que também gerou no francês "barre" e, então, no inglês "bar"), já "barro" provavelmente veio do substrato celta da Península Ibérica. Portanto, têm etimologias totalmente diferentes.

A palavra "barraca" parece ter vindo do catalão e pode ser cognata de "barro", mas a etimologia é incerta. Agora estes sufixos que citou, embora parecidos, nada têm a ver com a etimologia.

Comment: Gosto das tuas respostas Ergative, mas faltam referências a fontes... Os sufixos estão relacionados porque uma possivel derivação faria as palavras homografas. Sobre "barraca" sendo de origem incerta ainda pensei na possibilidade de ser (ao menos semanticamente) derivado de barra por analogia com tenda, ou seja uma casa feita de uma lona levantada por um pau. O barra vindo do latin (como diz o link do dicionário da pergunta) explica a entrada no francês que também é língua românica.

Comment: Posso começar a pôr algumas nas respostas hahahaha, peço desculpas. Mas homografia não faz palavras serem conectadas, é só uma coincidência ortográfica. E sim, note como no dicionário está escrito *barra, pois é uma plavra reconstruída no latim vulgar, uma vez que não existia no latim clássico, o que significa que foi importada de algum superstrato, supõe-se que foi dos francos! Dificilmente teria a ver com "barra", já que em catalão, por exemplo, é mais como uma cabana, que pode ser de pedra, barro etc